# appending links to a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a div that I want to append a snippet of code into onclick. The problem is that the code doesnt work. I think it has something to do with the onclick and my commenting out attempts using '/'

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#content_type_nav").html("<a id='add_content_container' onClick=/"window.location.href='create.php';/"><img id='add_content_icon' src='Site_Images/add_column.PNG'/></a>");
```

here is the html:

```
<div data-role="footer" id="content_type_nav" data-position="fixed">
        //I want the link to be inserted here
        <h1>Show me my...</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: and the problem you're having is...?

Comment: And you shouldn't use inline "onclick" anyway...

Comment: The link wont appear on click either. Is the code above correct? Am I suppose to use / near the "?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using jquery, you should delegate the onclick event.
And use prepend() to insert as first child.

```
var html = "<a id='add_content_container'><img id='add_content_icon' src='Site_Images/add_column.PNG'/></a>";

    $("#content_type_nav").prepend(html);
    $("#content_type_nav").on('click', 'a#add_content_container', function(){
             window.location.href='create.php';
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are replacing the content of that div. If you want to append to that div, you want to use the append() method instead of the html() method

Comment: I updated the question with the html. I also  display where I am trying to get the link to appear.

Answer (score 2):

From your code, try this:

```
$("#content_type_nav").append("<a id='add_content_container' onClick=window.location.href='create.php;'/><img id='add_content_icon' src='Site_Images/add_column.PNG'/></a>");
```

Comment: I tried this with prepend instead of append. but the link shows up, but it wont work. Thanks anyway though!